# How to know Fragment showed up on the screen [Not in the PagerAdapter]?

Tags: android, fragment, visibility

I am having trouble to figure out when the `Fragment` actually showed up on the screen and hide when some other `Fragment` replaces it. Means I need to know the methods which can help.

I have tried with following methods so far. These methods are not even calling. Cause I am not using `Fragments` inside the `PagerAdaper` (According to SO answers).

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
}

@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
}
```

Lastly I have tried with

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

They both are calling but the problem here is `onDetach` is calling after the second Fragment's `onAttach`.

So somehow I ended up with nothing.

Thanks for reading it!

Answer (score 1):

Use onDetach on firstFragment and onActivityCreated on second fragment.

Comment: Nice catch! But the the problem is that `onStop` being called after the next `Fragment's onAttach` method.

Comment: use onDetach on first fragment and onActivityCreated on second fragment.. onActivityCreated would be called after the first fragment detached.

Comment: yes it did the trick for me, update your answer I will accept it! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

May be below method is help you. It is calling after view visible.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Try below code for hide the fragment.

```
final Fragment hideFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                **.hide(hideFragment)**
                .addToBackStack(hideFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
```

When you are using .hide method then surely below method will call.

```
@Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    }
```

Comment: To know the `Show` status it's good but what about the `Hide` status?

Comment: if you are using transaction.add() with transaction.hide() method then sure @Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
}
 this method will call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isHidden()` to know the display of current state in the life cycle  callback of `Fragment`.

The state will be called in `onHiddenChange(boolean)`method, too. when a Fragment is attached, its default state is **SHOW**, so if you want the `onHiddenChange(boolean)` to be called, the premise is that you should explicitly call `show()/hide()` when using a transaction.

Such as this:

`getSupportFragmentManager().benginTranscation.add(...).show().commit();`